# ObjectOutputStream só salva o primeiro objeto

Tags: java, arquivo, stream-de-arquivos

Estou tentando manipular um arquivo em Byte com Java.
Na escrita do arquivo tenho o seguinte código:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("files\\Produtos.dat",true);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(P);
oos.close();

fos = new FileOutputStream("files\\Produtos.dat",true);
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(P2);
oos.close();

fos = new FileOutputStream("files\\Produtos.dat",true);
oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeObject(P3);
oos.close();
```

Eu fechei o arquivo e abri de novo porque é o que o programa original vai fazer, vai gravar novos objetos indefinidas vezes.
O código de leitura é o seguinte, onde produtos é um `ArrayList<Produto>`:

```
produtos.add((Produto)ois.readObject());
produtos.add((Produto)ois.readObject());
produtos.add((Produto)ois.readObject());
```

Na execução desse código só é salvo o primeiro objeto. Por que isso acontece?

Comment: Não é preciso fechar também o arquivo em si (fos) além do stream (oos) a cada ciclo?

Comment: @epx Faz tempo que não programo em Java, mas pelo que me lembro ao fechar um `Stream` ele propaga isso para os outros streams de quem ele depende (i.e. o `oos` vai fechar o `fos` automaticamente).

Comment: Blz, o problema real foi achado e respondido

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Conforme [essa pergunta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6578973/520779), o problema é que o `ObjectOutputStream` escreve um cabeçalho (*header*) no arquivo após escrever o primeiro objeto, que não deve ser escrito mais de uma vez. A solução proposta é utilizar o método [`reset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) entre uma escrita e outra, para permitir que mais de um objeto seja escrito sem que se inclua novamente o cabeçalho.

Entretanto, no seu caso particular isso não deve funcionar - já que o arquivo está sendo fechado e aberto de novo várias vezes. Além disso, ia exigir lógica para só incluir o cabeçalho se o arquivo está vazio, o que além de complicado pode não ser possível sem alterar o "programa original".

Minha sugestão é - com o `FileInputStream` ainda aberto - criar um novo `ObjectInputStream` cada vez que for ler um objeto:

```
produtos.add((Produto)(new ObjectInputStream(fis)).readObject());
produtos.add((Produto)(new ObjectInputStream(fis)).readObject());
produtos.add((Produto)(new ObjectInputStream(fis)).readObject());
```

Note que eu não fechei os `ObjectInputStream` criados - pois eles iriam fechar também o `FileInputStream` original, o que não é o que você quer. Ainda preciso fazer uns testes para verificar se essa solução resolve o problema de fato, mas deixo essa sugestão como um ponto de partida.

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que o o `ObjectOutputStream` escreve um cabeçalho no arquivo. Quando você abre novas *output streams* esse cabeçalho é escrito várias vezes no meio do arquivo.

A solução clássica seria deixar o `ObjectOutputStream` aberto (o que pode não ser desejável). Uma segunda alternativa seria abrir vários `ObjectInputStream`s conforme a resposta do @mgibsonbr; cada um deles lê um cabeçalho (porém, como ele mesmo apontou isso pode ter implicações; fico um pouco desconfortável não fechando recursos).

Porém, em [uma resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1195078/664577) no SOEN o usuário [Andreas_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/105224/andreas-d) apontou uma solução muito interessante envolvendo sobrescrever o método `writeStreamHeader()` com uma chamada para  `reset()`.

```
public class AppendingObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

   public AppendingObjectOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
      super(out);
   }

   @Override
   protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
      reset();
   }
}
```

### Lógica de uso (adaptação da resposta original):

Confira se o arquivo existe ou não, e então instancie a *stream* adequada:

No caso do arquivo existir nós estamos "apendando" e não queremos um cabeçalho:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new AppendingObjectOutputStream(fos);
```

No caso do arquivo não existir nós precisamos de um cabeçalho:

```
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
```

Você pode inclusive encapsular essa lógica em um método:

```
// Esboço; no código real trate exceções
public ObjectOutputStream openStream(File f) throws Exception {
   ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
   if (f.exists()) {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
      oos = new AppendingObjectOutputStream(fos);
   } else {
      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
      oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
   }
   return oos;
}
```

E o uso da *stream* fica transparente:

```
File f = new File("files\\Produtos.dat"); 
ObjectOutputStream oos = openStream(f); // Produtos.dat pode existir ou não
oos.writeObject(p);
oos.close();

oos = openStream(f); // Produtos.dat existe, apenda
oos.writeObject(p2);
oos.close();

// Versão Java 7 com try-with-resources
try (ObjectOutputStream oos = openStream(f)) {
   oos.writeObject(p3);
}
```

---

**P.S.** O [JEP 187](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/187) está exatamente pesquisando falhas e possíveis melhorias nos mecanismos de Serialização do Java. Quem sabe não sai algo interessante desse esforço de pesquisa.